# Import a print template from AutoCad into QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, autocad

I use QGIS (version 2.18.19) and my consulting colleagues use AutoCAD. A lot of our clients ask me to put my QGIS maps into AutoCAD format. Is there a way to simply import the print composer template from a CAD file directly into QGIS to then use?

Currently I have been saving as a PDF and then the CAD guys here import into CAD and create it that way. It is very time consuming and relies on other people.

If I could get the "look" of the AutoCAD format for QGIS then I could continue to happily make my beautiful maps in QGIS and not have to try and convert into AutoCAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The best way to do this is to recreate the CAD plot layouts in the print composer. This will be some work but it will pay off for sure.

A quick and dirty way to do this could be to print an empty plot layout from CAD and use it as a background image in QGIS. But it would be still a lot of work to make it all work and the result would be so-so due to the layout not being vector but raster...